# Alternative for ngInit inside custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume I have a simple directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDir', myDir);

function myDir() {

    var directive = {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: null,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template: '<button ng-click="vm.myDirVar = 1">',
        scope: {
            myDirVar: '='
        }
    };

    return directive;

}
```

If in the following example `vm.var` is `undefined`, my directive will not bind it to the isolated scope.

```
<my-dir my-dir-var="vm.var"></my-dir>
```

So in order to make it work, I'm using `ng-init` to set the default value for the`vm.var`, after that the binding to isolated scope works.

```
<my-dir my-dir-var="vm.var" ng-init="vm.var = var || 0"></my-dir>
```

The question is, how can I improve my directive so I can get rid of the `ng-init` while `vm.var` would still be binding even if it is `undefined` initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
 var directive = {
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function(){
        this.myDirVar = this.myDirVar || 0;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<button ng-click="vm.myDirVar = 1">',
    scope: {
        myDirVar: '='
    }
};
```

If is not a problem having a controller.

Comment: This works indeed. For some reason was overthinking the solution :P

Comment: It happens frequently to me!